# Join from multiple tables using WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, join, where-in

Im having a hard time finding anything on Google related to this problem.

What im trying to do is query from multiple tables with an unknown number of values using an IN statement like so...

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1 WHERE t1.t1_id IN ('12345223', '2343374') JOIN table_2 t2 WHERE t2.t2_id IN ('2164158194', '3232422423')
```

The code above demonstrates what I am trying to achieve. I'm not an SQL guru so im not entirely sure if what i'm going after can be accomplished this way or if there is a much better way to do it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Csan you give us the table structure, sample data and the result you whant to have?

Comment: `JOIN` needs to come before the `WHERE` clause. You can combine multiple `WHERE` clauses at the end with `AND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 t1 
JOIN table_2 t2 
ON t1.t1_id  = t2.reft1_id
WHERE t1.t1_id IN ('12345223', '2343374') 
AND t2.t2_id IN ('2164158194', '3232422423')
```

The "ON" clause will have to contain the two columns that are linked in the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answers seems that I had it mixed up a bit, this got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You got the order of your clauses mixed up. You should go 1.)`SELECT`, 2.) `FROM` with `JOIN`s, 3.) `WHERE`

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 t1 
JOIN table_2 t2 
WHERE t1.t1_id IN ('12345223', '2343374')
  AND t2.t2_id IN ('2164158194', '3232422423')
```

But your statement also seems to miss a `JOIN`-condition so it will either result in an error (it does in oracle) or (assuming t1_id and t2_id are primary keys) give you 4 result lines (seems it does so in mysql):

```
t1_id            t2_id
12345223         2164158194
12345223         3232422423
2343374          2164158194
2343374          3232422423
```

A `JOIN` without condition is almost never what you really want and if so it should be explicit in the statement and use `CROSS JOIN`.